# MAMP moodle project

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mamp, moodle

I am working on a moodle based project, which I inherited from someone else. Having copied the files into htdocs folder and started MAMP, the files still don't show in the browser. Instead, the browser automatically initiates a download. I might be required to change the config file, however, since I do not have much experience with php and SQL I am not sure what exactly. My part of the project is to develop html and css, but need to be able to run it locally first.

What do I need to do to get the files run locally? The route I use is localhost:8888/whatever/whatever/index.php

Comment: Now you need o install moodle first, for it you can put this address on your url bar `localhost:8888/yourMoodleFolderName/index.php`

Comment: Thank you. I managed to get PHP up and running by fixing .htaccess file. However, now I am getting a database error - Error: database connection failed. I am using OS X. People who had this issue seemed to be able to fix it by creating a symlink. Do you have any experience with that?

Comment: I am not sure if this work for you, Try to re-install moodle after deleting the `config.php`

Comment: That's exactly what I tried and it worked! After that I needed to setup ssl on Apache and that fixed the issue.

Comment: I m happy to hear this.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else runs into the same problem - Apache downloads php files instead of reading them - here is what helped me.

1. .htaccess file may need changes if the application has changed servers.
2. Delete (at least rename if you don't want to remove it) config.php and run the application through the browser. It should initiate install automatically.

To run php and SQL I used MAMP.